# How to overwrite an XML by another in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, file

I have an XML in the path `/bin/Debug` but I want that once received the data in string can overwrite that xml file. I'm looking for something simple like:

`doc = doc.LoadXml(servidor.datos)`

But I do not know if in this way the file is overwritten in that direction.
My code is as follows:

```c#
string ruta = Environment.CurrentDirectory += "/archivoJuego.xml";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(ruta);
servidor.EnviarRecibirInformacion(doc);
doc.LoadXml(servidor.datos);
```

Comment: `doc.Save(SavePath);` [Save(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.save?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlDocument_Save_System_String_) **Saves the XML document to the specified file. If the specified file exists, this method overwrites it.**

Comment: @blaze_125 Thaks very much. I didn't that info.